# hook is not being called in handleSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a hook that I want to call in handleSubmit. The data from this hook will be passed to another hook, and based on the response from the second hook, I want to push different pages.

The first hook:

```
const write = useContractWrite(
      {
        addressOrName: Address,
        contractInterface: Interface,
      },
      'entry',
      { 
        args: [firstAnswer.trim().toLowerCase(), secondAnswer.trim().toLowerCase()],
        overrides: { 
          value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01") 
       }
      }
    )
```

[Documentation for useContractWrite](https://wagmi.sh/docs/hooks/useContractWrite)

I have another hook that relies on the data of the useContractWrite hook:

```
const waitForTransaction = useWaitForTransaction({
      wait: write!.data?.wait,
      onSettled(data, error) {
        console.log("Settled", { data })
      }
    });
```

[Docs for useWaitForTransaction](https://wagmi.sh/docs/hooks/useWaitForTransaction#wait-optional)

And finally, my handleSubmit:

```
async function handleSubmit() {
      if (firstAnswer.length == 0 || secondAnswer.length == 0) {
        setInputError(true);
      }
      else {
        setInputError(false);

        //write
        const txn = write;
        // console.log(write + "writeData")

        //wait            
        // console.log(waitForTransaction.data + "waitData")
      }
    }
```

- Unfortunately, the `write` function is not being called in handleSubmit. So, I make it callable
- Changing the write to the following: `const { write } = useContractWrite` makes it callable `const txn = write();`
- But, I am unable to pass the `txn!.data.wait` to useWaitForTransaction like so:

  ````
   const txn = write();

   //wait
   waitForTransaction({wait: txn!.data?.wait});```
  ````
- The error I get when attempting to pass `txn.data.wait` to `waitForTransaction` is that the waitForTransaction is not callable `This expression is not callable.`
- So, I make it callable: `const { waitForTransaction } = useWaitForTransaction({...})`
- Now, I get the following error on the useWaitForTransaction Hook: `Property 'waitForTransaction' does not exist on type 'Pick<QueryObserverResult<TransactionReceipt, Error>, "data" | "error" | "isError" | "isLoading" | "isSuccess" | "isFetched" | "isFetching" | "isRefetching" | "refetch" | "fetchStatus"> & { ...; }'`

I am sure there is an easy fix to this, but I do not see where the issue lies. I have followed the docs to a tee and it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, the `waitForTransaction` is the whole return value, not a property of the returned value, so you need to drop the curly braces.

```js
const waitForTransaction = useWaitForTransaction({...})
```

Another problem you will have is that hooks cannot be called conditionally, so doing this is illegal in hook-land

```js
else {
  ...
  // cannot do this inside if () {} else {}
  const waitForTransaction = useWaitForTransaction({...})
}
```

---

Looking at the `wagmi` example, I would add the `handleSubmit` like this

```js
import { useContractWrite, useWaitForTransaction } from 'wagmi'

function App() {

  const [inputError, setInputError] = useState(false)

  const contractWrite = useContractWrite(
    {
      addressOrName: '0xecb504d39723b0be0e3a9aa33d646642d1051ee1',
      contractInterface: wagmigotchiABI,
    },
    'feed',
  )

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    const hasError = firstAnswer.length == 0 || secondAnswer.length == 0;
    setInputError(hasError)
    if (!hasError) {
      contractWrite.write()       // call write method of contract
    }
  }

  // use with conditional inside hook call
  const waitForTransaction = useWaitForTransaction({
    wait: contractWrite.data?.wait 
  })
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, the metamask window does not pop up when i do it this way, likely because contractWrite is not being called :(

Comment: Ok, that seems easy to do. See change above.

Comment: this works, but now I am running into an error in useWaitForTransaction that hash or wait is required. I can't use Hash, I need to use wait. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error as [@kalculated](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14390956/kalculated) "hash or wait is required". I managed to pass this error by **downgrading wagmi to 0.8.4.** The error was thrown on version 0.8.10.

I found this sample online that might be helpfull